# getApplicationContext() ... forcing close?

Tags: android

I'm implementing service binding into my application. However when i start my activity which binds to the service, the application force closes. Ive pin pointed that its due to the getApplicationContext() ... Heres my code and where it is called and used... 
All help is appreciated.
Thanks

```
 private LocalService mBoundService;
 private boolean mIsBound;


 Context context = getApplicationContext();



 private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
  public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
    // This is called when the connection with the service has been
    // established, giving us the service object we can use to
    // interact with the service.  Because we have bound to a explicit
    // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
    // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
    mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

    // Tell the user about this for our demo.
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast.makeText(context, "serviceconnected",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
    // This is called when the connection with the service has been
    // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
    // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
    // see this happen.
    mBoundService = null;
    Toast.makeText(context, "serviceDisconnected",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
};

    void doBindService() {
// Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
// class name because we want a specific service implementation that
// we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
// supporting component replacement by other applications).
bindService(new Intent(context, 
        LocalService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
     mIsBound = true;
 }

  void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
    // Detach our existing connection.
    unbindService(mConnection);
    mIsBound = false;
}
}

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   doUnbindService();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to bind service with activity,instead of using `getApplicationContext()`, you should use `getBaseContext()` or `this` keyword

Comment: if you want to start your service, call `startService` method inside your activity. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)

Comment: boomy boom BOOM! used doBindService(); then mBoundService.onStart(intent, 0,0);  thanks